# SQL Reporting Services unauthorized issue on Windows server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 on window server 2008 that is my report server.

My web application is in vs2010 which is on the other system. When I tried to show the report in report viewer it giving the following error:
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

I used the ProcessingMode.Remote.
I want to use the database credential for accessing the report (please keep in mind that I don’t want to use windows credential).

I have set the following authentication in reportserver.config file.

```
    <Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

And on data source I have selected the “Credential stored securely in the report server” option.
More over when I use the window server 2003 report server its working fine and report viewer showing the report successfully, It create problem on window server 2008.

Please someone help me to overcome this problem. Is report server required some specific configuration for window server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this occurs on the web server not keeping correct credentials to your data source.  Start by going to the SSRS site: h ttp://(servername)/(Reports) by default.

There are a few questions you should ask:

Is this a report accessed by many so should I set up a domain account for it?
Or is this report only available to a few people and they should be prompted?

Generally you can go into the problem report.  It will fail credentials.  You can click it's hyperlink, click data sources on the left pane.  You will see credentials set up.  If you want to store them as you said you did, they should appear here under the radio button 'credentials stored in report server'.  However many times an account should be listed here as a 'Windows account' or vice versa and is not.

I would also ensure once you get your data source down ensure your deployment settings are set to false for 'override data source'.  Hope this helps.